# Installing and calling Ipython inside virtual environment

Tags: python, scipy, ipython

I am using two different versions of `scipy` - standard and developer version. I switch between them using `virtualenv`. When I use interactive mode on the terminal with the standard `python`, I can see that I can use both versions depending on the `virtualenv` activated or deactivated.

However, `ipython` could not distinguish the `virtualenv` activated. It always selects the standard `scipy` installed. However, I already performed `pip install ipython` with the `virtualenv` activated and I could see that the ipython installed there in a separate folder. However, the same `ipython` is not invoked I believe. How to invoke the virtualenv ipython?

Comment: Have you tried to [install the virtualenv as a kernel in iPython](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs/)? Switching between virtualenvs should be possible from within iPython then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I found the solution. It is mentioned [here](https://howchoo.com/g/mgvizdexzje/how-to-make-ipython-work-in-a-virtualenv-virtual-environment). Before launching the `ipython`, performing the following command on the terminal solves the problem:

```
hash -r
```

From the same site:

> When you've run iPython previously in a shell session, that command was cached. This command simply resets the cache.